# .htaccess : Unable to add two rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have two rules - first one is to remove sub-directories(remove also the .php extension) in URL and the second one is to remove the .php extension in 404.php page.

> First rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1/$1.php [L,QSA]` -> which 
>   convert from `localhost/root/pages/student/student.php` to
>   `localhost/root/student`
>
> Second rule: `RewriteRule ^404/?$ 404.php [NC,L]` -> which 
>   convert from `localhost/root/404.php` to `localhost/root/404`

Both are working only if the other rule is commented but I can't make both rule work.

Can someone help me. I've been struggling for almost a day now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `^(.*)$` does of course match `404/`. Most likely simply switching the order of those rules around would help already. Not sure why you even have a `/404` URL in the first place. Your system should answer with HTTP status code 404 under the URL that was originally requested; if you externally redirect somewhere else first in that case, you are messing up the response; for example search engines will then follow that redirect, and not see a 404 status code for the originally requested resource any more.

Comment: No, switching the two rules dont work either. I use the 404 for redirecting unallowed users. What I am trying to do is remove the .php extension in 404.php. It works only if the other rule is disabled.

Comment: _"I use the 404 for redirecting unallowed users"_ - why? You should rather use a 403 Forbidden, and issue that for the URL that was requested, instead of redirecting elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply though. But my main issue is that I want to remove .php extension on that file(or any file). I can't seem to make it work because it's conflicting on the other rule which is RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1/$1.php. As I mentioned before, this rule will convert /pages/student/student.php to /student.